# Spring boot webflux deployment

Tags: spring-boot, netty

I have a project in spring boot reactive with webflux. Someone could tell me how to deploy it on Netty please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Spring boot starter webflux has an embedded Netty so including this dependency in your project and declaring a class with a main method will launch your reactive web application in Netty.

For example if you use Maven add those dependencies :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then in your class containing the main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Or if you want a fresh start with everything already configured and ready to code : https://start.spring.io.